# android 5 gui crash after appium test finished

Tags: android, python, appium

So, the trouble is when the appium python test is finished android OS has crashed. 
It looks like any app couldn't be opened, however, device kind of reacting on swiping beetween screens. 
To solve that I have to restart the device and things become well again. 
Interestingly, that it happens in about 60% cases.

the structure of my tests like so

```
PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p)
)

class SimpleAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1'
    desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'here_device_id 
    desired_caps['app'] = PATH(
        'path_to_apk'
    )
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = Main.desired_caps
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
    def test_add_contacts(self):
        el = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Add Contact")
        el.click()
        textfields = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.EditText")
        textfields[0].send_keys("Appium User")
        textfields[2].send_keys("someone@appium.io")
        self.assertEqual('Appium User', textfields[0].text)
        self.assertEqual('someone@appium.io', textfields[2].text)
        self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Save").click()s
        alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert(
        self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().clickable(true)').click()
        self.driver.press_keycode(3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

The proplem reproduced only in android 5,5+ devices. On adroid 4.4 everything is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was fixed in Android 5.1.